# How to retrieve messages history from Sinch iOS?

Tags: ios, chat, message, sinch

How can i retrieve **all** my messages from Synch in iOS?
I need to get my message history and i don't know how can i achieve this...
I don't know any methods at Sinch framework to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such history with Sinch IM. Its kept for delivery for 30 days, not an inbox

Comment: Ok, I'm afraid that i will need to use something like SQLite to do what i need. Thanks